# Promise not awaited on geocode

Tags: typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, promise, async-await

So I have the following code that I thought was awaiting correctly, but when I looked into it a little deeper, I found its just reacting very quickly (fast enough to be used in the angular template).

```
    this.dataService.getSomeData().subscribe(async (res) => {
      this.historyList = res;
      this.historyList.forEach(async (element) => {
        console.log('before')
        let address = await this.geocode(element);
        console.log(address)
        element.address = address
     });
     console.log('after');
```

and my geocode promise looks like:

```
 async geocode(item:Location):Promise<string> {
   return await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    const location = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({ location: location }, async (results, status) => {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        resolve(results[0].formatted_address);
      }
    });
  });
 }
```

Right now, the multiple "Before" logs and the one "After" Log will show in the console before any of the addresses come back.  Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?  VS Code doesn't have any issue with my await on the geocode method, so I am a little stumped.

Thanks

Comment: `.forEach(async (element) ` that callback is never being awaited on, so there is no synchronization for it.  If you switched it to a `for-of` loop it would await on each one before starting the next.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never found that on my own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `.forEach(async element=>` it is never going to await on the callbacks, if you wanted to do them in sequence you would switch it to a `for-of` loop:

```
this.dataService.getSomeData().subscribe(async (res) => {
  this.historyList = res;
  for(const element of this.historyList) {
    console.log('before')
    let address = await this.geocode(element);
    console.log(address)
    element.address = address
  }
  console.log('after');
}
```

Or to do them in parallel use `Promise.all`:

```
this.dataService.getSomeData().subscribe(async (res) => {
  this.historyList = res;
  // use map to get a promise for each.
  await Promise.all(this.historyList.map(async (element) => {
    console.log('before')
    let address = await this.geocode(element);
    console.log(address)
    element.address = address
 }));
 console.log('after');
}
```